# TF246017: team foundation server could not connect to the database after change Domain Account password

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, change-password

I need your help if possible in order to resolve the issue mentioned in message subject. I have a TFS installation in two servers: one for application and another for database both on AD Domain. For security reasons I need to change the domain user account password used for this application (the user account is the AD Domain Administrator).

I changed the password from Windows AD users and computers console and after that when I tried to access to TFS (http://servername:port/tfs) I received the TF246017 error. I restored the old password for the account and TFS started to work again.

I saw that this domain user account figures in TFS Admin console, under application tier and there is an option to upgrade the password of service Account. My questions are if it is necessary to run password upgrade from there in addition to doing it from the administrator of AD users and groups option and if there is/are another option/s that I should take into account to modify the password for this user account.

Thank you in advance for your attention and your help.
Best Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error info and root cause is very clearly. You need to update the password of your corresponding account.

There are two ways to achieve the account password update:

- [To use the administration console to change the password](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/admin/change-service-account-password?view=tfs-2015)
- [To use the TFSConfig utility to change the password:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/admin/change-service-account-password?view=tfs-2015)

To avoid TF246017 Error occur again, I would recommend you use the same user credential for SQL Server and TFS server. Ex: `domainname/tfs` is local admin to the server, sysadmin in SQL Server DB and also admin user to TFS server.

You could also check the Event log. The Windows Event Log is a good candidate where to look for the potential cause.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`tfsconfig`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/command-line/tfsconfig-cmd?view=tfs-2018) on the app tier server.

Something like `tfsconfig accounts /updatepassword /account:[account name] /password:[password]` should do the trick.

See also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/admin/change-service-account-password?view=tfs-2015